# What kind of software I can use to plot graphics like this? And how is this plotted?

Tags: transfer-function, gain, graphics

I am trying to plot the transfer function of a circuit.

What kind of software I can use to plot graphics like this, **without using circuit simulation software**?

[image]

I would like to understand things without using stuff pre-created by someone or some company.

How is this graphics created?

Thanks.

Comment: It says it in the graph title... Microcap. But you can use Excel python... Anything with plotting capability and ability to execute equations

Comment: Microcap is a circuit simulation software and I said, without using that kind of software. I don't think excel can do log graphs.

Comment: 1) why not use a simulator 2) YES excel can do log graphs.

Comment: Personally I use MATLAB or python but then I equally run Freq sweep in a circuit sim

Comment: @SpaceDog that software I used is the student edition and is free. I would encourage anyone to learn how to use a sim tool.

Comment: If you want to do it without a circuit simulator, then you will first have to learn to translate circuit diagrams to equations. Once you have the equation, plotting is easy. Getting the equation from the circuit is the difficult bit. Darned near any thing can then be used to generate the plot - including a pocket calculator and graph paper.

Comment: LT spice (any kind of spice almost), Matlab, Octave, Python, C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any plotting software can plot what you are after as this is basically just a log plot.

Excel:  change axis to log
Python+matplotlib: ax.set_yscale('log')
matlab: semilogx

The key is actually creating the frequency series data. Take your example plot. this is a phase lag compensator and thus the transfer function is: \$\frac{1 + \tau s}{1 + \beta \tau s}\$

\$\omega_m = \frac{1}{\tau \sqrt{\beta}}\$

\$f_m \approx 150Hz \$ from your example
\$\tau \approx \frac{1}{2000\cdot 2 \cdot \pi}\$ from your example
\$\beta \approx  \frac{1}{\tau \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 10} \$ from your example.

The overall transfer function is approx: \$ \frac{1 + \frac{j \omega}{12500}}{ 1 + \frac{j 2\cdot \omega}{125}}  \$

NOTE: significant rounding for example case otherwise this post filled with significant figures which is better suited in an application.

The real part is thus:

\$\frac{ \omega ^2}{781250 \cdot ( \frac{ 4 \cdot \omega ^2}{15625} + 1) } 
 + \frac {1}{ \frac{ 4 \cdot \omega ^2}{15625} + 1 }\$

and the imaginary part is:

\$\frac {- 199 \omega } { 12500\cdot ( \frac { 4 \cdot \omega ^2}{15625} +1} \$

Now you have the real and imaginary parts in terms of \$\omega\$ the frequency response can easily be plotted in any tool you wish with log capability.

So now the "easy part" is done... plotting is just a matter of a list of frequency and then calculating the gain and phase, plotting and setting the axis to log..

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1anJ0F8OVblT6hWWdXxBgnpfjr4idKqsHK8su3cAWMxQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

and for reference... with matlab:

[image]

I hope you can see the easy part is the plotting....

Comment: +1 for using live editor :)

Comment: @SpaceDog Does this answer solve your problem?